# Generic Task Visualizer / Metadata Manager

Tags: data-visualization, task-management, metadata

Is there a tool to help visualize automated tasks across an organisation? e.g.

- CRON Tasks
- Windows Tasks
- SQL Server Agent Tasks
- Other ETL / MFT / Reporting / Integration Tools / IFTTT tools
- Custom / Human Tasks

Ideally we can link to the scheduler databases to view them in real-time and add additional metadata to help visualise the nature of the tasks, possible clashes, linkages, responsible teams, who to contact in the event of a failure etc.

In other words, if I put on my "support hat", is there software to help me a view of all the scheduled tasks within my organisation?

I note there are free cloud-based project/team management tools that allow you to create recurring tasks - however a more technical lens would be helpful (e.g. link/import schedule).

Comment: Maybe with [BPMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Process_Model_and_Notation) diagramming [tools](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Business_Process_Model_and_Notation&section=11#Siehe_auch) (German Wikipedia lists a few products) you can visualize it, (but  proving that something is correct is difficult). You can waste a lot of time with BPMN and related technologies. So I leave this here as a comment.